# How to change default app programatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that has device admin rights. My app monitors received SMS's and passes the content through some logic. Can i change the default SMS app to my app programatically . My app checks for spam messages so it needs to read/write/update SMS db. I want a fix for kitkat.

I just noticed that the incoming SMS notification on my app are no longer notifications for new SMS that are received , but instead are "new Hangout message" notifications that are caused by hangouts receiving the incoming SMS. So my app is also not able to receive incoming text messages with SMS_RECEIVED.

Google's Android Developers Blog post about the new SMS API in Kitkat, said that nothing would change for apps using just SMS_RECEIVED and don't try to write the SMS to the SMS Provider.

1 I always believed that the SMS_RECEIVED broadcast is abortable. But the Android 4.4 APIs site says something different: "…when a new SMS arrives by listening for the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast, which is a non-abortable broadcast…"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can i change the default SMS app to my app programatically

Not directly. You can prompt the user to change the default SMS app.

> My app checks for spam messages

Repackage your code as a library and license it to SMS clients.

> So the Pebble app is also not able to receive incoming text messages with SMS_RECEIVED

Possibly the Pebble app is simply having other problems and is crashing before it notifies the Pebble. Or, possibly the Pebble app is updated for Android 4.4 and, since it knows it cannot stop the Hangouts notification, simply suppresses its own.

> Google's Android Developers Blog post about the new SMS API in Kitkat,said that nothing would change for apps using just SMS_RECEIVED and don't try to write the SMS to the SMS Provider

That is not what [this blog post says](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

> I always believed that the SMS_RECEIVED broadcast is abortable

This undocumented, unsupported broadcast had been an ordered, abortable broadcast through Android 4.3. That is no longer the case with Android 4.4, as you can tell by reading the aforementioned blog post:

> Note that—beginning with Android 4.4—any attempt by your app to abort the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast will be ignored so all apps interested have the chance to receive it.

Comment: in android 2.3.3 how can i prompt user to change default as in 4.4 Telephony.sms has a intent of ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT.

Comment: @AsimHabib: There is no concept of a default SMS client in Android prior to Android 4.4.